# Is jQuery image lazy load still solution for optimizing web load speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For sometime ago, I notice that few big design blog like SmashingMagazine, Noupe and other implement lazy loading on their image. I suppose this helps in optimizing their load time and save server resource.

Then I come to this jQuery [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for image, but the plugin is broke and not working for new browser. Would like to know is lazyload still recommended for optimizing website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how many images you have and how important they are, there are many solutions to improving your performance ( [you can find a presentation about the topic here](http://www.slideshare.net/mauricio.linhares/the-fast-the-slow-and-the-lazy)) and most of them depend on how your website is organized and what are our needs.

So, if your website has a lot of small icons that are reused in many different places ( [like amazon does](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/images/orangeBlue/navPackedSprites-US-22._V183711641_.png) ), you can use CSS sprites, you can use images encoded directly on the HTML, like google has been doing a lot and you can do lazy-load, so it all depends on your situation.

But going back to the lazy load plugin, look for javascript errors or things like that, if it doesn't work you can even build a lazy loader for yourself, should not be that complicated. Here's a hack that could possibly work (I did not run it, so I can't be sure):

```
<img lazy_loaded_src="/some_image.jpeg" class="lazy_loaded"/>
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
jQuery( "img.lazy_loaded" ).each( function () {
  var image = jQuery( this );
  image.attr( "src", image.attr("lazy_loaded_src") );
} );
```

This should have the same lazy-load behavior as long as you do it after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thank you. This clarify well.

Answer (score 1):

Odd that it is broke.  Maybe it's conflicting with your version of jQuery?

I use lazy load of images. It is a nice technique to use in certain situations.

Comment: Hmm.. Not compatible with new browser perhaps. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Tony shouldn't really be a problem as jQuery is just a javascript library... haven't looked at lazy load myself.